# How get value of Tag Name in XMLReader + how use that value for further analysis

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, simplexml

I have such XML File to parse (short version). 
What I need is to create new XML file which contain additional Tag: `<is_active><![CDATA[true]></is_active>`.
There is a simple condition, `<is_active>` is TRUE, when:
- current time (when we launch our code) is between hours given in <opening_times> Tag (we check also day); 
- otherwise `<is_active>` is FALSE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<offers>
<offer>
    <id><![CDATA[2109]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Sleek Frozen Sausages]]></name>
    <category><![CDATA[Sleek]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[Eum aut qui est delectus suscipit aut voluptas quaerat maiores architecto perferendis dolorum tenetur iure nemo omnis laboriosam voluptatem et iste molestias sed voluptas eum facilis aliquam tempora autem aspernatur ipsum corrupti cum corrupti quae dolor modi consequatur provident illo maiores eius aspernatur id nostrum nisi repellat enim a hic unde laboriosam possimus est ipsam qui mollitia nesciunt est culpa voluptatem sit dignissimos quidem facilis dolorem facilis et explicabo ea veniam quis architecto autem occaecati quaerat omnis reprehenderit doloribus labore saepe asperiores a ea possimus dolor necessitatibus numquam doloremque velit fuga ipsam numquam quia omnis voluptas voluptas rerum sint eveniet sit in error quia nemo delectus perferendis asperiores quam quam assumenda reiciendis sunt aut et saepe ea adipisci eum debitis odit similique consectetur nesciunt ducimus maxime sed consequuntur repellendus qui illum vero necessitatibus perferendis cumque optio voluptatibus et quas velit voluptatem tempore est et officiis tempora iusto rerum eum amet a qui corrupti ex nobis laborum eum assumenda velit laboriosam et sed sapiente accusantium officia enim doloremque perspiciatis quos ut rerum molestias ut ut aut omnis vitae placeat voluptas iusto distinctio ea molestias et at et aliquam libero non neque dicta quos numquam est non explicabo ipsa neque dolores rerum.]]></description>
    <price><![CDATA[252.65 EUR]]></price>
    <url><![CDATA[https://example.com/product/2109]]></url>
    <image_url><![CDATA[http://lorempixel.com/640/480]]></image_url>
    <opening_times><![CDATA[{"1":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"2":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"3":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"4":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"5":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"6":[{"opening":"10:00","closing":"22:30"}],"7":[],"timezone":"Europe/Warsaw"}]]></opening_times>
</offer>
<offer>
    <id><![CDATA[7673]]></id>
    <name><![CDATA[Ergonomic Soft Fish]]></name>
    <category><![CDATA[Rustic]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[Pariatur consectetur autem reiciendis ab ea est fugiat tenetur suscipit ut sit rem accusamus accusamus accusamus veniam commodi omnis quia minus ratione reprehenderit est porro omnis modi et ipsa aut itaque impedit inventore modi nisi nemo commodi nesciunt earum quia sed assumenda nulla quia qui neque laborum vitae nobis dolorem perspiciatis tenetur nisi asperiores eos itaque dolorem sit est nostrum sequi similique doloremque vero id voluptas exercitationem eveniet saepe non impedit aut neque aut sed molestiae aut cum hic consectetur facilis porro atque perspiciatis maiores maiores ut aut enim iste maxime dolores est dolores quaerat dolores error nisi et esse voluptas occaecati nostrum quasi vero porro natus iste molestiae totam culpa vero voluptate porro aut ut iusto non ullam quam aut itaque velit quis maiores nobis officia ut iure voluptatibus iure nihil optio repellendus eum similique eum in excepturi doloremque rerum cumque accusantium fuga sed sed odit vel qui nam eum iure sapiente magni et temporibus quis qui pariatur tempora odit explicabo et mollitia autem nihil autem repellat ut et laudantium ab dolores nisi porro fuga sed laudantium quae delectus debitis quaerat doloremque praesentium quod ullam accusamus architecto earum impedit esse sint sint fugiat nihil itaque ut ut aut provident.]]></description>
    <price><![CDATA[384.12 EUR]]></price>
    <url><![CDATA[https://example.com/product/7673]]></url>
    <image_url><![CDATA[http://lorempixel.com/640/480]]></image_url>
    <opening_times><![CDATA[{"1":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"2":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"3":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"4":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"5":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"6":[{"opening":"14:00","closing":"23:00"}],"7":[],"timezone":"Europe/Warsaw"}]]></opening_times>
</offer>
</offers>
```

I get values of Tag Name `<opening_times>` in all `<offer>` using XMLReader(); by code below:

```
<?php
$XMLReader = new XMLReader();
$XMLReader->open('feed_sample.xml');
while ($XMLReader->read()){
    if ($XMLReader->name === 'offer' && $XMLReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT){
        $element = array();
        $element = simplexml_load_string($XMLReader->readOuterXml());
        echo $element->opening_times;
    }
}
```

but I would like to get value `<opening_times>` from only one `<offer>` and I don't know exactly how to do that.

Ok, further I created such code. I invented it like that: if current day is correct with day given in `<opening_times>` check if current hour is correct with hour given in `<opening_times>`. Here is my second doubt. How to get value of day or hour from `<opening_times>` if those are not attributes? Can you give me a advice?

```
function compare_current_hour(){
    $today = date('l');//aktualny dzień
    $now = date('h:i');//aktualna godzina
    if ($today === 'Monday'){
        $day = 1;
    } elseif ($today === 'Tuesday'){
        $day = 2;
    } elseif ($today === 'Wednesday'){
        $day = 3;
    } elseif ($today === 'Thursday'){
        $day = 4;
    } elseif ($today === 'Friday'){
        $day = 5;
    } elseif ($today === 'Saturday'){
        $day = 6;
    } elseif ($today === 'Sunday'){
        $day = 7;
    }

    if ($day === $day_xml){
        if ($now === $day_xml_opening_hours){
            //dodaj Tag Name <is_active>
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it is not too long.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `XMLReader::$name`. This is the full tag name of an element node. I prefer using `XMLReader::$localName` which is the node name without the namespace alias.

XMLReader is used for huge XML files. Usually to load parts representing an item in a list. The item then expanded into DOM. This loads only one item (`offer`)  node and its descendant into memory. So the main reason for using XMLReader is memory consumption. It can improve processing time, but only if you filter on the XMLReader level. In my experience it is not worth the additional effort and complexity for most cases.

You're serializing and parsing a part of the XML feed. XMLReader can directly expand into DOM. Then you can use Xpath expressions to fetch values from the expanded node:

```
$offerID = '7673';
$openingTimes = '[]';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open(getFeedURL());

// bootstrap a DOM document
$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// find the first "offer" element in the document
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'offer') {
    continue;
}

// while the current node has the name "offer"
while ($reader->localName === 'offer') {
    
    // expand to DOM
    $offer = $reader->expand($document);
    // use Xpath to fetch ID
    $id = $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $offer);
    // compare ID
    if ($offerID === $id) {
        // fetch opening times and break loop
        $openingTimes = $xpath->evaluate('string(opening_times)', $offer);
        break;
    }
    
    // move to the next offer sibling
    $reader->next('offer');
}
$reader->close();

var_dump(json_decode($openingTimes, TRUE));
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["opening"]=>
      string(5) "14:00"
      ["closing"]=>
      string(5) "23:00"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["opening"]=>
      string(5) "14:00"
      ["closing"]=>
      string(5) "23:00"
    }
  }
  ...
```

If you're not familiar with Xpath and prefer SimpleXML you can import the DOM node.

```
$offerID = '7673';
$openingTimes = '[]';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open(getFeedURL());

// bootstrap a DOM document
$document = new DOMDocument();

// find the first "offer" element in the document
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'offer') {
    continue;
}

// while the current node has the name "offer"
while ($reader->localName === 'offer') {
    
    // expand to DOM
    $offerNode = $reader->expand($document);
    // import to SimpleXML
    $offer = simplexml_import_dom($offerNode);
    
    // cast first "id" child to string
    $id = (string)$offer->id;
    // compare ID
    if ($offerID === $id) {
        // read opening times and break loop
        $openingTimes = (string)$offer->opening_times;
        break;
    }
    
    // move to the next offer sibling
    $reader->next('offer');
}
$reader->close();

var_dump(json_decode($openingTimes, TRUE));
```

If the feed is small enough you could load it into DOM and use a single Xpath expression to fetch specific opening times:

```
$offerID = '7673';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load(getFeedURL());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$openingTimes = $xpath->evaluate(
    "string(
      //offer[normalize-space(id) = '$offerID']
      /opening_times
    )"
);

var_dump(json_decode($openingTimes, TRUE));
```

Or SimpleXML:

```
$offerID = '7673';

$offers = simplexml_load_file(getFeedURL());
 
$opendingTimes = (string)(
  $offers->xpath(
    "//offer[normalize-space(id) = '$offerID']/opening_times"
  )[0] ?? ''    
);

var_dump(json_decode($openingTimes, TRUE));
```